# overstability vs resonance: what is the difference?

Tags: resonance, stability, accretion-disk

Reading about discs, I encountered the word 'overstability' that its difference with resonance is not clear to me. Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: http://cc.oulu.fi/~jrschmid/Overstability/Overstability.html , http://www.wladimirlyra.com/research.html are two references that I used to initially to attempt an answer, but I just don't know enough to write a proper one. The references do define overstability. Apologies if you know them already.